# An anime in which people/androids are turned into pills which everyone takes instead of eating

Tags: galaxy-express-999

All I remember is watching an anime early in the morning on Sci-Fi channel.

I remember a scene of a young boy with a gun in a futuristic setting. He was watching a large conveyor belt with old androids and/or humans being dumped into a machine which turns them into supplement pills that everyone takes instead of eating.

It could have been a movie or an OVA, I'm not sure. Also, I am not sure when it aired on Sci-Fi, but it had to be anywhere from 2000-2006 and it was in English.

Comment: Sounds like it could be one of those bizarre OVAs from the boom era like "Psychic Wars", "Venus Wars", "Vampire Wars", etc. Can't recall this particular scene, though.

Comment: Bizarre is a bit of an understatement, I dropped in just to ask "the f**k?".

Comment: Reminds me a bit of kaiba.

Comment: This question is really bothering me. Why does nobody know the answer yet?

Comment: I believe if seen something similar, where you could be upper class human, or lower class human. And you had to work your *ss of to earn i believe some sort of stamp. And the humans that did not work hard enough got turned into food pills to keep the other people alive

Comment: Supplement info on my previous comment. Acording to my colleague this scenario reminds him of a music video from a long time ago. With gorrilaz like animations.

Answer (score 5):

Galaxy Express 999 Adieu.

The conveyor belt is bright purple and covered with rows of bodies of non-robotic people, going towards a bright white light. The boy with the gun, Tetsuro, stands watching the process with 3 of his traveling party, as the bodies are processed. They are dropped through what looks like lines of electricity and a white orb is extracted which is contained in a tiny pill that is essentially robot food. It is referred to as the flame of life. – This link is bad quality but is on the scene. https://youtu.be/RI-b9_o3nSk?t=5523

Comment: @Dimitri mx I don't know if its the one you were thinking of, still have to watch it again. Been looking for it for 5 years, found using the "human resource" trope http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HumanResources

Comment: Can give a brief description of the scene you think the OP is referring to?

Comment: The conveyor belt is bright purple and covered with rows of bodies of non-robotic people, going towards a bright white light. The boy with the gun, Tetsuro, stands watching the process with 3 of his traveling party, as the bodies are processed. They are dropped through what looks like lines of electricity and a white orb is extracted which is contained in a tiny pill that is essentially robot food. It is referred to as the flame of life.